# String replace with multiple items

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have two pandas dataframes. One contains text, the other a set of terms i'd like to search for and replace within the text. I have created a loop which is able to replace each word in the text with a term however it's very slow, especially given that it is working over a large corpus.

My question is:
Is there a more efficient solution that replicates my method below?

Example text dataframe:

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'Text': ['here is some random text', 'random text here', 'more random text']}
text_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Example terms dataframe:

```
d = {'Replace_item': ['<RANDOM_REPLACED>', '<HERE_REPLACED>', '<SOME_REPLACED>'], 'Text': ['random', 'here', 'some']}
replace_terms_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Example of current solution:

```
def find_replace(text, terms):
for _, row in terms.iterrows():
    term = row['Text']
    item = row['Replace_item']
    text.Text = text.Text.str.replace(term, item)
    return text
find_replace(text_df, replace_terms_df)
```

Please let me know if anything above requires clarifying. Thank you,

Comment: Can you define "very similar terms instead of exact terms"? My instinct this is not trivial and potentially better asked as a *separate question*.

Comment: Good point jpp. I'll remove this and ask as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) + [`str.replace`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) on the three columns, and assigning the results to the column at once, reduced the time by 50% (~400us to ~200us using `%timeit`):

```
text_df['Text'] = [z.replace(x, y) for (x, y, z) in zip(replace_terms_df.Text, replace_terms_df.Replace_item, text_df.Text)]
```

Comment: Thanks Ami! I was wondering if there was a way of vectorising also for performance improvements?

Comment: You're very welcome, but I share your question whether there's a vectorized way to do this (to the best of my knowledge, there isn't).

Comment: Does the 'terms' dataframe always have to be equal to or larger than the  'text' dataframe in length? I've been running some tests and it runs into issues when the terms are shorter than the text.